# manage-bde protectionaserrorlevel not working

Tags: batch-file, bitlocker

Heyo, I'm writing a batch file to routinely check if bitlocker is enabled.  However, I realized that before I could get to any of the juicy automation parts, I'm getting an error by just running manage-bde -status c: -p (as admin).  Would someone please provide an example of correct usage of manage-bde -status c: -p?  I'm working on a 64-bit Windows 10 machine.  Here is my script and output.  Thanks!

```
@ECHO OFF
manage-bde -status c: -p
ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
PAUSE
EXIT
```

The result is what I would usually get when I run manage-bde -status c: with the addition of an error message:

```
Volume C: [Windows]
[OS Volume]

    Size:                 471.56 GB
    BitLocker Version:    None
    Conversion Status:    Fully Decrypted
    Percentage Encrypted: 0.0%
    Encryption Method:    None
    Protection Status:    Protection Off
    Lock Status:          Unlocked
    Identification Field: None
    Key Protectors:       None Found

ERROR: While performing the operation, a component unexpectedly returned FALSE.
-1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example uses an alternative method to the manage-bde command, which you may find useful.

The variable `%ProtectionStatus%` should hold a value of either `0`, `1`, or `2`.
Lines `6` onwards should output messages to explain what those integers mean.
*You could always change that part as per your requirements.*

```sh
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "ProtectionStatus=" & For /F Tokens^=* %%G In ('WMIC.exe
 /NameSpace:\\ROOT\CIMV2\Security\MicrosoftVolumeEncryption Path
 Win32_EncryptableVolume Where "DriveLetter='%SystemDrive%'" Call
 GetProtectionStatus 2^>NUL ^| find.exe "ProtectionStatus "')Do Set /A %%G 2>NUL
If Defined ProtectionStatus (If %ProtectionStatus% Equ 0 (Echo The volume is^
 not encrypted, partially encrypted, or the encryption key for the volume is^
 available in the clear on the hard disk.)Else If %ProtectionStatus% Equ 1 (
Echo The volume is fully encrypted and the encryption key for the volume is not^
 available in the clear on the hard disk.)Else Echo The volume is either^
 locked, or its protection status cannot be determined.)Else Echo An unknown^
 error occurred.
Pause
```

Please note that this also needs to be 'Run as administrator'